# Calculate frequency based on a filtered field, and put the value in another field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, grouping, frequency

I'm a python beginner. 
I'm working on one feature class, i would like to group this feature based on `group_ID` field, and then for each one of this group i would like to calculate the number of rows with `risk_level_def` respectively `high`, `medium`, and `low`. Once i have these numbers i would like to put them in `num_HR_def`, `num_MR_def` and `num_LR_def` .

I tried with following script, that is working but the numbers i get are wrong.

```
fa_complete = r"mypath"

myList = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("fa_complete", "group_ID")]
myList = list(dict.fromkeys(myList)) # delete duplicates

for i in myList:    # for each ID within list:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('fa_complete', "NEW_SELECTION", "risk_level_def = 'high'")
    count_HR_def = arcpy.GetCount_management('fa_complete') 
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("fa_complete", "num_HR_def", count_HR_def)
```

Then i'm doing the same for all the others risk levels. I'm sure i'm not using  the most efficient way. How can i do this calculation and improve the script?

[image: img_1]
[image: img_2]

Comment: I'm sorry i cannot share my dataset. Thanks for your advide, i'll try

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you have two FeatureClasses: `fa_complete` used to get different `group_id`, and `point_Buffer` that has the field to count (`risk_level_def`) and where you want to update frequency fields?

Comment: Sorry,it was my mistake. I have only one feature class, "fa_complete" (i modified the script) and i would like to update with frequency always in the same feature. Grouping by `group_id`, for each group i would like to calculate the number of high, medium and low risk.

Comment: There is no need for python. Use Pivot table - Summary statistics - join output back to original table - copy table - rename fields.